# How to configure the HTTPS proxy server for docker image which build to run spring boot application?

Tags: docker, spring-boot

How to configure the HTTPS proxy server for docker image which builds to run spring boot application? Docker image created using docker for windows and base image openjdk:8-jdk-alpine;

tested with the following configurations:

docker file for image:

```
    ENV HTTPS_PROXY "https://user_name:password@IP:port"
```

config.json file:

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add :

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
```